# Laravel Firebase multiple database support

Tags: laravel, firebase, laravel-5, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Laravel project with firebase database. I wanted to create a new database for the same firebase project. So I created a new firebase DB and gave the firebase DB URI to the .env file and other configurations. Cache is also cleared. Now throughout the project, there is no old URI. Instead of the old URI of firebase, the new one is replaced. But still old DB is connecting and old DB is updating when working. Are there any configurations to do in order to fix my issue?

I used "kreait/firebase-php": "^4.18" extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating Firebase project, they gave us a firbase json private key to store it on laravel codebase. Inside that json file, there is a project id. That project id and database name should be equal. By setting it I fixed that issue.